# Ruby use gsub within string interpolation

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm trying to use gsub within a string interpolation

```
puts "Some words #{Lookup1[input[2]].gsub("[", "(")} some more words"
```

The input array looks like this:

```
input = [0,22,["Accounting","Customer Relations"],nil,nil,nil,nil]
```

My goal is to replace [] with ()

Thanks

Comment: Is your goal to replace native ruby syntax to use parentheses instead of square brackets to declare arrays in the first place?

Comment: When asking about a problem with your code, it helps if you show the desired output. See "[mcve]".

Comment: Got it, thanks @theTinMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> puts "Some words #{input[2].to_s.gsub('[','(').gsub(']', ')')} some more words"
#=> Some words ("Accounting", "Customer Relations") some more words
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Gagan

Comment: This answer is by all means worse than the one given by @steenslag.

Comment: @mudasobwa :agree, it's better to use `tr` then use `gsub` multiple time, but in OP's post he tried to use `gsub` and fail to get his required output, so I saw the solution his way, what mistake he was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to change the string representation of the input[1] array:

```
puts "Some words #{Lookup1[input[2]].inspect.tr("[]", "()")} some more words"
```